# Grabbing the info from beautiful soup and putting it into a text file?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I have started to learn how to scrape information from websites using urllib and beautifulsoup. I want to grab all the text from this page (in the code) and put it into a text file.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
base_url = "http://www.galactanet.com/oneoff/theegg_mod.html"



url = (base_url)
soup = Soup(urllib.urlopen(url))

print(soup.get_text())
```

When I run this it grabs the text although it outputs it with spaces between all the letters and still shows me HTML, unsure why though.

```
i   n   '   >      Y   u   p   .       B   u   t       d   o   n      t       f   e   e
```

Like that, any idea's?

Also what would I do to put this info into a text file for me?

(Using beautifulsoup4 and running ubuntu 12.04 and python 2.7)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some trouble with the encoding, so I changed your code slightly, then added the piece to  print the results to a file:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

base_url = "http://www.galactanet.com/oneoff/theegg_mod.html"

url = (base_url)
content = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = Soup(content)
# print soup.original_encoding
theegg_text = soup.get_text().encode("windows-1252")

f = open("somefile.txt", "w")
f.write(theegg_text);
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `html2text`:

```
import html2text as htmlconverter
print htmlconverter.html2text('<HTML><BODY>HI</BODY></HTML>')
```